# "msg": "unable to apply conditional to result" in Ansible

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I am trying to running the following task and it keeps through out the following error, any idea to fix it ?

```
fatal: [SW1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "unable to apply conditional to result"}
```

Here is the playbook and NXOS is a group of hosts

```
- name: SNMP ACLs Configuration 
  hosts: NXOS
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: SNMP ACLs for NXOS
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - copy http://1.2.3.4/tftpboot-directory/snmp_acl.txt running-config vrf default
        wait_for:
         - result[1] contains Copy complete.
```

Comment: it appears you are referencing an undefined variable, which I would have expected to provide a more illustrative error message but is still suspicious (or, I guess you just truncated your posted snippet)

Comment: Issues seems to be resolved by changing the index to 0 like this below; ```- result[0] contains Copy complete.

Comment: then feel free to add your own answer and accept it, although that puts your question at risk of closure because it is unlikely to help anyone in the future

Comment: thanks @mdaniel, I just poted the answer, sorry i am a newbie here and learning things..

Answer (score 0):

Issues seems to be resolved by changing the index to 0 like this below;

```
- result[0] contains Copy complete.
```